# Type for 64 digit number

Tags: c++, bigint

Which C++ type is large enough to represent a 64 digit decimal number like

3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592 ?

Comment: @KobyDouek 64 *digits*, not bits.

Comment: Probably none. `long long` is required to be at least 64 *bits*, but could theoretically be longer. You have to check your compiler's manual.

Comment: Search and research arbitrary or multiple precision number libraries.

Comment: The misfortunes of not being able to de-flag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing "out of the box" for this: you'd need a 64 * log(10) / log(2) bit integral type. (A `std::int256_t` from the future would suffice!)

If you're not going to manipulate the number mathematically in any way, then use a `std::string`.

Otherwise, consider using the large number library in Boost: www.boost.org. That stuff has a habit of making it into future C++ standards. Note that

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using namespace boost::multiprecision;
```

yields the `int256_t` type.